# Problems performing 1D-FDTD for dispersive dielectric uisng lorentz model in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to model a dispersive dielectric using the Lorentz model in Julia, more specifically I am trying to obtain the frequency-dependent reflectivity of the material. I am ultimately trying to replicate the results in [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1809725115#:%7E:text=Parametric%20gain%20in%20phononic%20four,to%20control%20phonon-polariton%20waves.).

I have the set of update equations:

[image]

along with the coefficients:

[image]

I am trying to implement this system but the numerical result I obtain is different than the analytical one. Results from my current implementation:

[image]

For some context, my source is a Gaussian pulse with central frequency 26 THz and bandwidth 6 THz. I also use the parameters fmax, nmax, d (the thickness of the slab) to determine the minimum wavelength I want to be able to resolve with my cell size through the relations lambda=c/(fmax*nmax), dzi=lambda/20,N = ceil(d/dzi), dz = d/N. Now I obtain the result above when I put in fmax=10,nmax=1, and d=304.8 which are not the expected values. When I put in the actual values fmax=32 (as the maximum freqeuncy in the source), nmax=16 (since the analtical result gives n=16+16i near the resonance), d=38.1 I get the following:

Wrong? result for the right values

[image]

The solution for the actual values results in a sin^2 pattern just as in the case with no dispersion. The distance between the peaks for a linear material can be found analytically to be c/(2*nmax*d) and here the peculiar thing is that the distance between the peaks is the same as the mean of this expression for all the different frequencies (as nmax is a function of frequency now since the material is dispersive). I remain dumbfounded by these results and can't figure out why my implementation is not working.

I have my code written in julia below (note: I am also taking D/epsilon_0 Q/sqrt(epsilon_0) and J/sqrt(epsilon_0)):

```
#Initialisation

    #Units
    ps = 1e-12 #s
    μm = 1e-6 #m
    THz = 1e12 #Hz
    F_per_m = ps^-4*μm^3 #(ps⁴*A²)/(kg*μm³)
    H_per_m = ps^2/μm #(kg*μm)/(ps²*A²)

    #Grid Resolution (Wavelength)
    c = 299792458*ps/μm #μm/ps
    λₘᵢₙ = c/(nₘₐₓ*fₘₐₓ) #μm
    Nₗ = 20 #number of points per wavelength
    Δₗ = λₘᵢₙ/Nₗ #μm

    #Grid Resolution (Structure)
    Nₛ = 4
    Δₛ = d/Nₛ #μm
    
    #Initial Grid Resolution (Overall)
    Δzᵢ = min(Δₗ,Δₛ) #μm
    
    #Snap Grid to Critical Dimension(s)
    dᵣ = d #μm
    N = ceil(dᵣ/Δzᵢ)
    Δz = dᵣ/N #μm
    
    #Determine Size of the Grid
    Nᵣ = Int64(N+23) #number of total cells
    z = (1:Nᵣ)*Δz
    
    #Compute Position of Materials
    n₁ = 13 #first cell of the material
    n₂ = Int64(n₁+round(d/Δz)-1) #last cell of the material
    
    #Add Materials to the Grid
    μᵣ = 1 #relative permeability of material
    μₛ = 1 #relative permeability of source
    εₛ = 1 #relative permittivity of source
    nₛ = sqrt(μₛ*εₛ) #refractive index of source
    UR=fill(μₛ,Nᵣ) #relative permeability across the grid
    UR[n₁:n₂].=μᵣ
    
    #Calculate Time Step
    nb = 1 #refractive index of the boundary
    Δt = (nb*Δz)/(2c) #ps
    τ = 1/(2*6) #1/(2fₘₐₓ) #ps
    t₀ = 6τ #ps
    tₚᵣₒₚ = (nₘₐₓ*Nᵣ*Δz)/c #ps
    T = 12τ+tc*tₚᵣₒₚ #ps
    Steps = Int64(ceil(T/Δt)) #number of total time steps
    
    #Compute the Source Functions
    ω = 26*2π #THz
    t = (0:Steps-1)*Δt #ps
    δt = (nₛ*Δz)/(2c)+Δt/2 #ps
    Eₛ = exp.(-((t.-t₀)./τ).^2).*exp.(im*ω.*(t.-t₀)) #located at source
    Hₛ = -sqrt(εₛ/μₛ).*exp.(-((t.-t₀.+δt)./τ).^2).*exp.(im*ω.*(t.-t₀.+δt)) #located at source-1
    
    #Parameters for Equation of Motion
    μ₀ = 4π*1e-7*H_per_m #H/m
    ϵ₀ = 1/(c^2*μ₀) #F/m
    ε₀, εₓ = ones(Nᵣ), ones(Nᵣ)
    Γ, Ω, α, β = zeros(Nᵣ), zeros(Nᵣ), zeros(Nᵣ), zeros(Nᵣ)
    ε₀[n₁:n₂].= 9.66
    εₓ[n₁:n₂].= 6.52
    Γ[n₁:n₂].= 0.2 #THz
    Ω[n₁:n₂].= 24.9 #THz
    Ω₀ = sqrt(ε₀[n₁]/εₓ[n₁]*Ω[n₁]^2) #THz
    
    #Compute Update Coefficients
    #UR *= nb/(2*ri) .*(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*ri*Δz/c))./(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*Δt))
    #ε₀ *= nb/(2*ri) .*(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*ri*Δz/c))./(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*Δt))
    #εₓ *= nb/(2*ri) .*(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*ri*Δz/c))./(sin.(π*fₘₐₓ*Δt))
    meh = nb./(2*UR)
    mjj = (2 .-Γ.*Δt)./(2 .+Γ.*Δt)
    mqj = (2 .*Ω.^2 .*Δt)./(2 .+Γ.*Δt)
    mej = (2*Ω.*sqrt.((ε₀.-εₓ)).*Δt)./(2 .+Γ.*Δt)
    mhd = nb/2
    mde = 1./(εₓ)
    mqe = (Ω .*sqrt.((ε₀.-εₓ)))./(εₓ)
    
    #Initialize fields and Boundary Terms
    E, H, J, Q, D             =zeros(ComplexF64,Nᵣ),zeros(ComplexF64,Nᵣ),zeros(ComplexF64,Nᵣ),zeros(ComplexF64,Nᵣ),zeros(ComplexF64,Nᵣ)
    e₁, e₂ = 0,0
    h₁, h₂ = 0,0

    #Initialize Reflected and Transmitted Fields
    Er = zeros(ComplexF64,Steps)
    Et = zeros(ComplexF64,Steps)

    #Setup Fourier Transforms
    Freq = fftshift(fftfreq(Steps,1/Δt))
    Esf = fftshift(fft(Eₛ))

    #Main FDTD Loop
    for T in 1:Steps
        #Record H at Boundary
        h₂ = h₁
        h₁ = H[1]
            
        #Update H from E
        for nz in 1:Nᵣ-1
            H[nz] = H[nz] + meh[nz]*(E[nz+1] - E[nz])
        end
        H[Nᵣ] = H[Nᵣ] + meh[Nᵣ]*(e₂-E[Nᵣ])
            
        #H Source
        H[1] = H[1] - meh[1]*Eₛ[T]
    
        #Update J from Q and E
        for nz in 1:Nᵣ
            J[nz] = mjj[nz]*J[nz] - mqj[nz]*Q[nz] + mej[nz]*E[nz] 
        end
    
        #Update Q from J
        for nz in 1:Nᵣ
            Q[nz] = Q[nz] + Δt*J[nz]
        end
    
        #Update D from H
        D[1] = D[1] + mhd*(H[1] - h₂)
        for nz in 2:Nᵣ
            D[nz] = D[nz] + mhd*(H[nz] - H[nz-1])
        end
    
        #D Source
        D[2] = D[2] - mhd*Hₛ[T]
            
        #Record E at Boundary
        e₂ = e₁
        e₁ = E[Nᵣ]
            
        #Update E from D and Q
        for nz in 1:Nᵣ
            E[nz] = mde[nz]*D[nz]-mqe[nz]*Q[nz]
        end
            
        #Update reflected and transmitted fields
        Er[T] = E[1]
        Et[T] = E[Nᵣ]
    end

    #Determine optical properties from FDTD values
        
    Erf = fftshift(fft(Er))
    Etf = fftshift(fft(Et))

    r = Erf./Esf
    tr = Etf./Esf

    Ref = abs.(r).^2
    Trn = abs.(tr).^2
    Con = Ref.+Trn

    n = (1 .-r)./(1 .+r)
    
    ε₁ = real(n).^2-imag(n).^2
    ε₂ = 2*real(n).*imag(n)

    #Determine optical properties from analytical solution
    εₜₑₛₜ = εₓ[n₁].+(Ω[n₁]^2*(ε₀[n₁]-εₓ[n₁]))./(Ω[n₁]^2 .-Freq.^2 .-im.*Γ[n₁]*Freq)
    nₜₑₛₜ = sqrt.(εₜₑₛₜ)
    Rₜₑₛₜ=abs.((1 .-nₜₑₛₜ)./(1 .+nₜₑₛₜ)).^2
```

As mentioned above I tried changing the values of fmax, nmax, and d to get more accurate results and did manage to except at the wrong values.